# Landing page as a dialog in Jquery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'd like to have the landing page of my project behave like a Jquery Mobile dialog.

This would function similarly to Groupon's location selection when you hit the site logged-out.

How can I do this? I tried copying various parts of the rendered dialog pages, but this makes the content vanish or behave strangely in other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work?

- http://jsfiddle.net/WMvAs/17/
- http://jsfiddle.net/WMvAs/18/ (function)

JS

```
var showInitialDialog = false;

if (showInitialDialog === false) {
    $.mobile.changePage('#landing', 'pop', false, true);
    showInitialDialog = true;
}

$('#home').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
    if (showInitialDialog === false) {
        $.mobile.changePage('#landing', 'pop', false, true);
        showInitialDialog = true;
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Home Page</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Page 2</li>
            <li><a href="#home">Home Page</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="dialog" id="landing">
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Landing Dialog</li>
            <li><a href="#home">Go Home</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this kind of programmatic setup, but it looks like the best answer for now. Thanks!